# ElementTree : insert method and bad indentation output

Tags: python, insert, indentation, elementtree, pretty-print

I use this code to insert a new node in the original .xml (file taken from the ElementTree documentation) :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


my_xml = """
    <country name="Togo">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2000</year>
        <gdppc>3</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
"""


new_contry = ET.fromstring(my_xml)
root.insert(1,new_contry)

tree.write('essai_insert_output.xml')

root = tree.getroot()
```

But the result destroys the right indentation between the new node and the next one :

```
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E" />
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W" />
    </country>
    <country name="Togo">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2000</year>
        <gdppc>3</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E" />
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W" />
    </country><country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N" />
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W" />
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E" />
    </country>
</data>
```

The new node `<country name="Togo">`is well placed but at the end of it, we have this collision :

```
</country><country name="Singapore">
```

How to cure this effect?

Comment: It's just a matter of formatting. The structure is right.

Comment: @dabingsou Ok, but how is it possible to improve the formatting? I have to transform XML files for somebody, and the point is to provide well formatted XML outputs (I tried the lxml module, but had the same issue).

Comment: Here is an example of formatting the output.

Comment: You can make the output look prettier by just adding some whitespace to the [`tail`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail) of the `new_contry` element. Like this:  `new_contry.tail = "\n   "`.

Comment: Here is how you can get nice pretty-printed output with lxml: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42577999/407651

Answer (score 1):

As of Python 3.9, a new method named [indent()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.indent) has been added to `xml.etree.ElementTree`, which can be used to generate pretty-printed XML output without using another module or library.

To fix your example in Python 3.9+, just add the following line right before writing the tree to the file:

```
    ET.indent(tree, '    ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Format output.

```
from xml.dom import minidom

dom = minidom.parse('country_data.xml')
with open('dom_write.xml', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as fh:
    dom.writexml(fh, indent='', addindent='\t', newl='', encoding='UTF-8')
```